# Why does not appear editor tab under the appearance menu in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to view the `PHP` file in **WordPress** admin panel, but this option does not appear under the `Appearance` menu.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Open wp-config.php on your host,and Search for :

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

change true to false

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
```